# How many password combination?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many password combinations if you can have up to 8 letters, uppercase or lowercase, with only letters and no numbers or special characters?

My attempt: $$52+52^2+52^3+52^4+52^5+52^6+52^7+52^8$$ because there are 52 possible at each place and you can have up to 8 letters which means you can have either 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 or 8 letters. Is this correct? My reasoning could be off. Thank you!

Comment: Seems correct. There could be one more for the empty password.

Comment: Well since they ask for a password, I assumed they mean you have to have at least 1 letter. But thank you for answering!

Comment: My experience with Windows 2000 showed that asking for a password doesn't mean asking for a non-empty password.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming non-empty passwords your answer is fine. Note that you can compute this as $$\frac{1 - 52^9}{1 - 52} = 54.507.958.502.661$$ if you allow the empty password, and that $-1$ if not.